# Simplify matrix algebra

Tags: simplifying-expressions, linear-algebra

I'm trying to simplify some matrix linear algebra, for example, simplify

$$\big(a1\times(A1\cdot A2)\big)\cdot\Big(a2\times A3\cdot A4+(a3\times A5)\cdot(a4\times A6)\Big)^{T}$$

where lower case variables $(a1-a4)$ are numbers and upper case variables $(A1-A6)$ are matrixes. "$\times$" is the Times function and "$\cdot$" is the Dot function, $\text{T}$ is the transpose operation.

I have these math identities for my matrixes in my case:

$$
(A\cdot B)^{T}=B^{T}\cdot A^{T}\\
(A+B)^{T}=A^{T}+B^{T}\\
c\times(A+B)=c\times A+c\times B\\
c^{T}=c
$$

so the expresion will simplify into
$$
a1~a2~A1\cdot A2\cdot A4^{T}\cdot A3^{T}+a1~a3~a4(A1\cdot A2\cdot A6^{T} \cdot A5^{T})
$$

My major question is how can I use Simplify or FullSimplify to do this simplification in MMA in an elegant and extensible way? For extensible I mean that one can easily add more operation rules into the simplification identities, for example, we could add inverse operation and its identities such as $(A\cdot B)^{-1}=B^{-1}\cdot A^{-1}$ and $(A^{-1})^T=(A^T)^{-1}$ etc.

---

Here is my try (I'm a novice and apparently my code is not elegant in any sense so please don't hesitate to advice suggestions or to point out any mistakes I made, I'm very welling to learn from you guys. And please pardon my poor English :P):

1.First simplify $(A\cdot B)^{T}$ to $B^{T}\cdot A^{T}$ and  $(A+B)^{T}$ to $A^{T}+B^{T}$, I define a transformation function

```
g1[expr_] := expr /. Transpose[A_] :> If[Head[A] == Dot || Head[A] == Times || Head[A] == Plus,
 Head[A] @@ Reverse[Transpose /@ A], Transpose[A]]
```

which changes `Transpose[Dot[A,B]]` to `Dot[Transpose[B],Transpose[A]]`, and `Transpose[Plus[A,B]]` to `Plus[Transpose[B],Transpose[A]]`. And then define a ComplexFunction that prefers the form that Transpose is in the inside, for example, prefer `Dot[Transpose[B],Transpose[A]]` to `Transpose[Dot[A,B]]` :

```
cpfunc[expr_] := Module[{funcls},
 If[Length[expr] > 1, 0, 
  If[Depth[expr] <= 2, 0,
   funcls = Reverse[Part[#, 0] & /@ (Level[#, {0, Depth[#] - 2}])] &@expr;
   If[Max[Position[funcls, Transpose]] - Max[Position[funcls, Dot]] < 0 ||
      Max[Position[funcls, Transpose]] - Max[Position[funcls, Times]] < 0 || 
      Max[Position[funcls, Transpose]] - Max[Position[funcls, Plus]] < 0,
   10^3, 0] (*gives punishment when found Dot inside Transpose, etc.*)
]]]
```

This works for `Transpose[A1.B1.C1]`:

```
Simplify[Transpose[A1.B1.C1], TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, g1},
  ComplexityFunction -> cpfunc]
(*Transpose[C1].Transpose[B1].Transpose[A1]*)

Simplify[Transpose[a*A1], TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, g1}, 
  ComplexityFunction -> cpfunc]
(*Transpose[a] Transpose[A1]*)
```

2.Second simplify $(a\times A)^{T}$ to $a~A^{T}$ :
I define a transformation function:

```
g2[expr_] := 
 expr /. Transpose[x_] :> If[x ∈ Reals, x, Transpose[x]]
```

then

```
Simplify[g2@Simplify[Transpose[a*A1], TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, g1}, 
   ComplexityFunction -> cpfunc], 
   Assumptions -> a ∈ Reals && A1 ∉ Reals]
(*a Transpose[A1]*)
```

Initially I was trying to do something like this but it doesn't work(could you point out the mistakes?)

```
g2[expr_] := expr /. (Transpose[x_];/NumberQ[x]) :> x
Simplify[Transpose[a*A],TransformationFunctions->{Automatic,g1,g2},
   ComplexityFunction->cpfunc,Assumptions->a∈ Reals&&A1∉Reals]
(*Transpose[a] Transpose[A]*)
```

3.Simplify the whole expression:

```
Simplify[(a1*A1.A2).Transpose[a2*A3.A4 + (a3*A5).(a4*A6)], 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, g1},
 ComplexityFunction -> cpfunc]
(*
 (a1 A1.A2).((Transpose[a4] Transpose[A6]).(Transpose[a3] Transpose[A5]) 
 + Transpose[A4].Transpose[A3] Transpose[a2])
*)

Simplify[g2@%, Assumptions -> {a1 ∈ Reals, a2 ∈ Reals, 
 a3 ∈ Reals, a4 ∈ Reals, A1 ∉ Reals, 
 A2 ∉ Reals, A3 ∉ Reals, 
 A4 ∉ Reals, A5 ∉ Reals, 
 A6 ∉ Reals}]
(*
 (a1 A1.A2).(a2 Transpose[A4].Transpose[A3] 
 + (a4 Transpose[A6]).(a3 Transpose[A5]))
*)
```

the output is
$$
(\text{a1} \text{A1}\cdot\text{A2})\cdot(\text{a2} \text{A4}^{\mathsf{T}}\cdot\text{A3}^{\mathsf{T}}+(\text{a4} \text{A6}^{\mathsf{T}})\cdot(\text{a3} \text{A5}^{\mathsf{T}}))
$$
This final answer is close to the result I want to achieve. I tried to go further but without any luck. Here is my thinking(questions) about this:

1. Is there some more elegant way to do this? For example, it is possible to set some kind of attributes to these different operations so that Dot, Times, Pulse etc have different priority in the calculation, and one can sort them directly by their attributes in order to simplify or expand an expression?
2. I'm very curious how MMA Expand an algebra expression like `(a + b)*(c + d*e)`.
3. How to make a transformation function work on different assumptions? For example, when only x is a number, that the transformation `Transpose[x_]:>x` will apply.

Comment: Just checking : the second identity holds in your specific problem, not in general, right ?

Comment: Hi @b.gatessucks, yes it's a special case, I'll make it clear in my question, thanks for point it out.

Comment: You might find useful our Quantum Mathematica add-on (it is free) for doing these kind of operations, see for example http://homepage.cem.itesm.mx/jose.luis.gomez/quantum/v7algebra.nb and http://homepage.cem.itesm.mx/jose.luis.gomez/quantum/v7triangles.pdf I hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

I was really intrigued by this problem and I tried multiple solutions before posting one here.
The most elegant approach I found is to use `ReplaceRepeated` with a custom list of scalar variables.

In order for it to work we need the proper rule set

```
rules := {
  T[Dot[A_, B__]] :> T[Dot[B]].T[A],
  T[Plus[A_, B__]] :> T[A] + T[Plus[B]],
  T[a_ A_] /; MemberQ[scalars, a] :> a T[A],
  T[a_] /; MemberQ[scalars, a] :> a,

  x__.(y_ + z__).w___ :> (x.y.w) + (x.z.w),
  (x___).(a_ y_).(z___) /; MemberQ[scalars, a] :> a (x.y.z)
  }
```

Let's see what they are doing. The first two,

```
  T[Dot[A_, B__]] :> T[Dot[B]].T[A],
  T[Plus[A_, B__]] :> T[A] + T[Plus[B]],
```

correspond exactly to your first two math identities. Using a sequence (`B__`) instead of a single expression (`B_`) allows to apply this rules one argument at the time.
The third and the forth,

```
  T[a_ A_] /; MemberQ[scalars, a] :> a T[A],
  T[a_] /; MemberQ[scalars, a] :> a,
```

provide for some simplification whether a scalar is involved,
and the last two,

```
  x__.(y_ + z__).w___ :> (x.y.w) + (x.z.w),
  (x___).(a_ y_).(z___) /; MemberQ[scalars, a] :> a (x.y.z)
```

implement some properties of the dot product.

This is the expression which has to be simplified:

```
expr = (a1*A1.A2).T[a2*A3.A4 + (a3*A5).(a4*A6)]
```

This the result without any assumptions:

```
In[484]:= expr //. rules // Expand

Out[484]= (a1 A1.A2).T[a2 A3.A4] + (a1 A1.A2).T[a4 A6].T[a3 A5]
```

And this providing an explicit list of scalars:

```
In[485]:= Block[
 {scalars = {a1, a2, a3, a4}},
 expr //. rules // Expand
 ]

Out[485]= a1 a2 A1.A2.T[A4].T[A3] + a1 a3 a4 A1.A2.T[A6].T[A5]
```

where I use `Expand` only to avoid the automatic collection of `a1`.

---

All of that can also be packed into a function

```
MatrixSimplify[expr_, s : _List : {}] :=
 Module[{},
  If[OwnValues[$scalars] === {},
       $scalars = {}
   ];
  Block[
   {$scalars = Join[$scalars, Flatten[{s}]]},

   With[{rules = {
       T[Dot[A_, B__]] :> T[Dot[B]].T[A],
       T[Plus[A_, B__]] :> T[A] + T[Plus[B]],
       T[a_ A_] /; MemberQ[$scalars, a] :> a T[A],
           T[a_] /; MemberQ[$scalars, a] :> a,

       x__.(y_ + z__).w___ :> (x.y.w) + (x.z.w),
       (x___).(a_ y_).(z___) /; MemberQ[$scalars, a] :> a (x.y.z)
       }},

    expr //. rules // Expand
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

`MatrixSimplify` must be provided with an expression and an optional list of scalars.

```
In[562]:= expr // MatrixSimplify

Out[562]= (a1 A1.A2).T[a2 A3.A4] + (a1 A1.A2).T[a4 A6].T[a3 A5]

In[563]:= MatrixSimplify[expr, {a4, a1}]

Out[563]= a1 A1.A2.T[a2 A3.A4] + a1 a4 A1.A2.T[A6].T[a3 A5]
```

It also relies on the global variable `$scalars` (the bit of code within the `If` statement is to check whether `$scalar` is initialized and, if not, it does set it to an empty list), so you can do something like

```
In[564]:= $scalars = {a1, a2, a3, a4};

In[565]:= expr // MatrixSimplify

Out[565]= a1 a2 A1.A2.T[A4].T[A3] + a1 a3 a4 A1.A2.T[A6].T[A5]
```

---

P.S.

An alternative way to do this is by using `MatchQ` instead of `MemberQ`. This makes it possible to specify the scalar variables with patterns as in

```
$scalars = a[_] | b[_] | ...
```